# Configuring LAMP Environment in Linux Mint 8 using XAMPP- installing Memcache

Tags: linux, php, xampp, memcached

Okies, I have successfully installed the XAMPP and added virtual hosts and am able to make database calls and stuff. The problem I am facing is while trying to enable the memcache module. 
Currently trying to configure using these links.

1. h??p://theindexer.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/installing-a-lamp-stack-on-linux-using-xampp-for-linux/
2. h??p://theindexer.wordpress.com/2008/06/11/installing-xdebug-on-xampp-for-linux/
3. http://lynxbites.blogspot.com/2009/09/steps-to-install-memcache.html

The problem I am facing is while starting the phpize from /opt/lampp/bin/phpize

I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/opt/lampp/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

Can any one tell me wat to do for this error and if anyone has any useful links for configuring memcache on linux using XAMPP please paste here.

Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you are installing XAMPP specifically instead of using your trusty package manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, then it seems like you're in the wrong place when trying to run the command.

You need to download the source from somewhere, extract it into a folder, `cd` into that folder and then run the program.

So:

```
 wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.5.tgz
 tar -xvf memcache-2.2.5.tgz
 cd memcache-2.2.5
 /opt/lampp/bin/phpize
```

and then go back to following your instructions.

Comment: Is it compatible with php5.5 too?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Mint based on debian/ubuntu?  Why don't you just install the existing packages for php and mysql, mint probably also includes the php5-memcache package that is in ubuntu.  This will be less work, and more secure in the long run.

Comment: Currently using Linux Mint 8. While try to install from the repo its giving the 404 error. Hence as i couldnt find a proper instruction set to setup a LAMP environment from scratch switched to XAMPP.

Comment: you had one problem(a bad mirror maybe?)  Now you have two problems.